# php: Instantiate class on-the-fly

Tags: php

Is it possible to instantiate a class from a string, without declaring another variable before ?

It's usually done writing

```
$className = 'myClass'
$instance  = new $className();
```

but it could be handy to have it shorter like for example

```
$instance  = new ${'className'}();
```

The purpose is to have objects created (under condition) inside a loop without use of extra vars...

**Edit :** $className is dynamic, it is hard coded above to explain the situation

Comment: PHP 5.3 has some new syntax so it might work there. Another solution would be to use `eval`. Why do you have the 'no extra vars' constraint?

Comment: Also, if there is no variable with the class name in it, then you can just write `$instance = new classname();` anyway.  If you know the class name beforehand, you can hard code it; if you don't, it will already be in a variable.  Perhaps you can expand your question further to explain your needs more clearly.

Comment: I don't get it. If you're not using a variable for it to be dynamic, and hard-coding `'className'` string, why can't you just do `new className()`

Comment: Actually, first having a light code, and avoid memory overuse, because all of this use is already loops and heavy mySQL transactions

Comment: You can unset the variable after the loop, and do mysql_free_result (or their equivalent) to free up some code. How much is your php memory set?

Comment: You should look for optimization somewhere else You're not likely to see any benefit from such actions but You can always unset the variable like @Panagiotis said if it really bothers You.

Comment: Then unsetting it is, and so much for having it shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a factory function (or class/method) that takes a class name as a parameter, and then call it with the result of your dynamic PHP code that generates the string. You might consider it a bit cleaner but it's not going to save you any memory or speed.

```
class foo { }
function factory($class) { return new $class(); }

foreach (...) {
    $instance = factory(<some code that returns the string 'foo'>);
}
```

Comment: Except for memory usage which doesn't seem to be the real deal, this solution is interesting... I'm using this dynamic instantiation into different methods, so it may be a way to centralize it and have better control.

Comment: This example is wrong. factory should be a static method in foo and new class instantiated with foo. See the below example...

Comment: This is certainly not "wrong." While factories are classically implemented as a class (precisely the reason why I indicated "or class/method" in the answer) there is absolutely no syntactic or moral requirement to do so.

Comment: Also, you don't know what class is going to be instantiated, so you can't put the factory in the definition for that class. I.e., you'd have to create a new generic utility class that contains nothing but a universal factory method. That's no less "wrong" than my solution.

Answer (score 2):

See [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#PHP).

```
class Foo {
    static function factory($class, array $args = null) {
        return new $class($args);
    }
}

// class factoring; returns a new instance of requested class ($className)
Foo::factory($className);
```

I added optional arguments array if you want to set some class properties.

```
// pass some values for class constructor
Foo::factory($className, array('arg1' => 1, 'arg2' => 2, 'args3' => 3));
```

Furthermore, you can build "fluid" interfaces so you can "chain" methods when you use that pattern:

```
Foo::factory($className)->method1()->method2(array('param' => 'value'))->etc();
```

where `method1()`, `method2()` must `return $this` (the object itself) to chain multiple method calls in one line.

Answer (score 1):

It's one extra variable, does it really make much of a difference? The answer is that unless you use eval (which comes with security issues) it isn't possible to do it any shorter than your first example.